# Items are not aligning in one row in less resolution in html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am designing html content like this
[image]

But for me both icons (trash and floppy) are going out of row.
If I increase resolutions to 1480*300 floppy is coming at right place but trash can is not moving.
[image]

I tried all the things to my knowledge best but its not working.

Here is html code

```
   <div className="notes-box">
    <div className="row">
      <Select
        containerClassName="note-type"
        name="selectNoteDropDown"
        id="selectNoteDropDown"
        value={this.state.selectedNote}
        label="Select Note type"
        required={true}
        objectKeyValue={["key", "value"]}
        options={this.getOptionsList(this.state.noteSelectionList, true)}
        onChange={this.updateValue}
        isLabelNumber={true}
        sort={false}
        //width={250}
      />

      <div>
        <input
          type="image"
          onClick={(e) => this.setState({ showDiscardNote: true })}
          src="/assets/images/notes/trash-can.png"
          class="Trash-can-addNote"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div className="separator" />
    <div className="group row">
      <div>
        <TextArea
          label=""
          name="noteText"
          id="noteText"
          containerClassName="AddNoteTextArea"
          value={this.state.noteText}
          onChange={this.updateValue}
          required={true}
          disabled={false}
          readOnly={false}
          hide={false}
          //width={200}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="link-style">
          <i
            class="fa fa-floppy-o"
            aria-hidden="true"
            style={{ color: "#8b64c6" }}
            onClick={this.addCustomerNotes}
          ></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is CSS code

```
                  .customer-note {
     .notes-history-header-boxes {
       width: 49px;
       height: 24px;
       border-radius: 12px;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin-bottom: 5px;
       .notes-history-ball {
         width: 16px !important;
         height: 16px !important;
         object-fit: contain !important;
         margin-bottom: 4px !important;
         margin-left: 4px !important;
         padding-top: 0%;
       }
     }
     .nh-day-row {
       padding-left: 25px;
       width: 35% !important;
     }
     .nh-date-row {
       padding-left: 45px;
       width: 35% !important;
     }
     .nh-day {
       margin-left: 6px !important;
       width: 16px;
       height: 20px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.37;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #555555 !important;
     }
   
     .nh-date-and-time {
       margin-left: 5px !important;
       width: 58px;
       height: 19px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #555555;
     }
     .nh-Exclamation {
       margin-top: 7px;
       margin-left: 14px;
       width: 4px;
       height: 16px;
       object-fit: contain;
     }
     .nh-month {
       width: 31px !important;
       height: 20px !important;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.2;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #2b2b2b !important;
       margin-left: -10px !important;
     }
     .nh-year {
       width: 55px;
       height: 29px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 24px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.2;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #2b2b2b;
       margin-top: -29px !important;
     }
     .nh-iconBG {
       width: 30.7px;
       height: 30.7px;
       background-color: #d5d5d5;
       border-radius: 50%;
       display: inline-block;
   
       .nh-image {
         display: block;
         object-fit: contain !important;
         align-items: center !important;
         padding: 5px !important;
       }
       padding-right: 10px !important;
     }
   
     .nh-ball {
       width: 25px;
       height: 25px;
       background-color: #d5d5d5;
     }
     .nh-splitter {
       width: auto !important;
       height: 1px;
       opacity: 0.1;
       border: solid 1px #000000;
     }
     .Line-Copy {
       width: 1px;
       opacity: 0.5;
       border: solid 1px #000000 !important;
       // min-height: 123px !important;
       height: 100% !important;
       background-color: black !important;
     }
     .nh-header-notes-count {
       width: 8px;
       margin-left: 5px;
       height: 19px;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #6a6a6a;
       text-align: right !important;
       display: inline-block;
     }
   
     .notes-history-all-time-15 {
       width: 101px;
       height: 19px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #555555;
     }
     .Select-Note-type {
       width: 29% !important;
       height: 17.8% !important;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #2b2b2b;
       padding-top: 13% !important;
     }
     .notes-history-title {
       margin-left: -20px !important;
       width: 120px !important;
       height: 19px !important;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px !important;
       font-weight: bold !important;
       font-stretch: normal !important;
       font-style: normal !important;
       line-height: normal !important;
       letter-spacing: normal !important;
       color: #2b2b2b !important;
       padding-left: 24px !important;
       padding-right: 4px !important;
       bottom: 10px !important;
     }
     .nh-year {
       width: 55px;
       height: 29px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 24px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.2;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: var(--jarvis-grays-01);
     }
     .nh-tiles {
       width: auto !important;
       min-height: 123px !important;
       overflow-y: auto !important;
       border-radius: 20px;
       border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       background-color: #ffffff !important;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       margin-right: 24px;
     }
     .ch-ball-orange {
       width: 12px;
       height: 12px;
       object-fit: contain;
       background-color: #ff6347;
       border-radius: 50%;
       display: inline-block;
       margin-left: 4px !important;
       padding-top: 5%;
       .exclamation {
         width: 2px;
         height: 10px;
         object-fit: contain;
         background-color: var(--jarvis-primary-white);
       }
     }
     .nh-ball-orange {
       width: 16px;
       height: 16px;
       object-fit: contain;
       background-color: #ff6347;
       border-radius: 50%;
       display: inline-block;
       margin-bottom: -2px !important;
       margin-left: 4px !important;
       padding-top: 0%;
       .exclamation {
         width: 2px;
         height: 10px;
         object-fit: contain;
         background-color: var(--jarvis-primary-white);
       }
     }
     .notes-history-ball {
       width: 16px !important;
       height: 16px !important;
       object-fit: contain !important;
       margin-bottom: 2px !important;
       margin-left: 4px !important;
       padding-top: 0%;
       display: inline-block;
       // object-fit: contain;
       // padding-left: 16px !important;
       // padding-right: 2px !important;
     }
     .notes-history-ball-body {
       width: 16px;
       height: 16px;
       // object-fit: contain;
       // padding-left: 24px !important;
       // padding-right: 2px !important;
     }
     .notes-history-important {
       width: 83px;
       height: 21px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.3;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #ff6d5c;
       padding-left: 14px !important;
     }
     .Trash-can-addNote {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 12px;
       height: 14px;
       object-fit: contain;
       //float: right !important;
       margin-right: 0px !important;
       margin-top: 5px !important;
   
       //  margin-left: 80px !important;
     }
     .Trash-can {
       width: 12px;
       height: 14px;
       object-fit: contain;
       float: right !important;
       margin-right: 10px !important;
       //margin-top: -15px !important;
       margin-left: 80px !important;
     }
     .an-save {
       right: -55%;
       top: 10px;
       float: right !important;
     }
     // .selectRow {
     //   display: inline-block !important;
     //   width: 80% !important;
     // }
     .notes-box {
       width: auto !important;
       height: auto !important;
       min-height: 110px;
       border-radius: 20px;
       border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       background-color: white !important;
       padding-bottom: 8px !important;
       margin-bottom: 8px !important;
   
       .form-component.note-type {
         display: block !important;
         padding-top: 2px !important;
         padding-left: 15px !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         .form-component {
           width: 100% !important;
         }
         label {
           font-size: 10px !important ;
         }
         #selectNoteDropDownText {
           width: 100% !important;
           font-size: 12px !important;
         }
         .input-label {
           width: 70% !important;
           height: 15px;
           font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
           font-size: 12px;
           font-weight: normal;
           font-stretch: normal;
           font-style: normal;
           line-height: normal;
           letter-spacing: normal;
           color: #2b2b2b;
           border-style: hidden !important;
         }
         .select-options {
           width: 70% !important;
         }
         .select-options li {
           width: 70%;
           height: 30px;
           font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-weight: normal;
           font-stretch: normal;
           font-style: normal;
           line-height: normal;
           letter-spacing: normal;
           color: #404040;
         }
       }
     }
     .AddNoteTextArea {
       padding-left: 15px !important;
       width: fit-content !important;
       .input-label {
         width: 45% !important;
         border-style: hidden !important;
       }
       #noteText {
         width: 100% !important;
       }
       label {
         font-size: 12px !important ;
         width: 30% !important;
       }
       .input-label.has-error {
         width: 50% !important;
         border-style: hidden !important;
       }
       TextArea {
         border-style: hidden !important;
         width: fit-content !important;
       }
     }
     .important-notes-css {
       margin-top: 5px !important;
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: auto !important;
       height: 21px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 13px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.3;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #ff6d5c;
     }
     .empty-day {
       margin-left: 10px;
     }
     .empty-page {
       margin-top: 50%;
       text-align: center;
       width: 180px;
       height: 114px;
       font-family: BebasNeue;
       font-size: 22px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       text-align: center;
       color: #555555;
     }
     .RG {
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: 99px;
       height: 19px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #404040;
     }
     .CS {
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: 17px;
       height: 19px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #404040;
     }
     .Note-Copy {
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: auto !important;
       min-height: 18.2px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.3;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #404040;
       min-height: 40px !important;
       display: block !important;
     }
     .Agent-Name {
       margin-left: 5px;
       margin-top: auto;
       width: auto;
       height: 15px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 9px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.2;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #6a6a6a;
       position: relative !important;
     }
     .Date-and-Time {
       margin-left: 10px;
       position: relative;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-right: 5px;
       float: right;
       width: auto;
       height: 15px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 10px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.2;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       text-align: right !important;
       color: #6a6a6a;
     }
     .Ball {
       width: 12px;
       height: 12px;
       object-fit: contain;
       margin-bottom: 1px !important;
     }
     .Note-History-Btn {
       width: 100px !important;
       margin-top: 15px !important;
       height: 25px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 10px !important;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       text-align: left;
       color: #2b2b2b;
       padding-right: 0%;
       padding-left: 13px !important;
       padding-bottom: 20px !important;
     }
     .Add-Note-Btn {
       width: 95px !important;
       height: 25px !important;
       font-size: 9px !important;
       padding-left: 10px !important;
       text-align: right !important;
       float: right !important;
       margin-right: 10px !important;
       float: right !important;
     }
     .Jwidget-Images-Size {
       width: 12px;
       height: 12px;
       object-fit: contain;
       margin-bottom: 3px !important;
       margin-left: 2px;
     }
     .Jwidget-Images-Box {
       width: 24;
       height: 17px;
       border-radius: 12px;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       align-items: center !important;
       padding-right: 5px;
     }
     .Jwidget-Images-Number {
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       font-size: 12px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: normal;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #6a6a6a;
       margin-left: 1px !important;
       margin-right: 0px !important;
       margin-bottom: 3px !important;
       padding-bottom: 3px !important;
     }
     .separator {
       border-top: solid 1px #000000;
       opacity: 0.1;
     }
     .Notes-Label {
       width: 42px;
       height: 20px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold !important;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.37;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #2b2b2b !important;
     }
     .Notes-Count {
       width: 9px;
       height: 20px;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-stretch: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       line-height: 1.37;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       color: #808080 !important;
     }
     // .body-content{
     //   padding-left: 13px !important;
     //   padding-right: 13px !important;
     // }
     .box-size {
       overflow-y: auto;
       display: block;
       height: 440px !important;
     }
     .Button-Row {
       display: inline-block !important;
     }
     .discard-note {
       width: auto !important;
       z-index: 1 !important;
       height: auto !important;
       min-height: 110px;
       max-height: 130 !important;
       max-width: 280px !important;
       top: 95px;
       left: 13px;
       border-radius: 16px;
       opacity: 0;
       box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
       background-color: #ffffff !important;
       color: #f4f4f4 !important;
       position: absolute;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 16px;
       .title {
         width: auto !important;
         height: 29px;
         font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
         font-size: 24px;
         font-weight: bold;
         font-stretch: normal;
         font-style: normal;
         line-height: 1.2;
         letter-spacing: normal;
         text-align: center;
         color: #2b2b2b;
       }
       .body-message {
         width: auto !important;
         height: 38px;
         padding-left: 26px !important;
         padding-right: 26px !important;
         font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-weight: normal;
         font-stretch: normal;
         font-style: normal;
         line-height: normal;
         letter-spacing: normal;
         text-align: center;
         color: #2b2b2b;
       }
     }
   }
```

can someone please help me out ?

NOTE:- Text  Area and Select are predefined components
Thank you in advance

Comment: make a codesanbox or something like that hard to follow your issue

Comment: I can not make code sandbox as  Text Area and Select  internal component which I have imported.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the fix
I used d-flex justify-content-between.